# Change image display from base64 to src according to the email client

Tags: css, outlook, gmail, html-email, signature

I want to view the images inside the email signature on all email clients.
Initially I created my signature using the classic:

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1e0siJmU...">
```

This worked great for gmail and apple mail but outlook gives problems as it doesn't download images for security. Annoying! I have seen that instead outlook desktop displays images without problems if they are embedded via base64 code like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/...
```

. Now, however, it does not work in gmail as it does not even display the images and therefore the related social links.

So I thought of doing a sort of if clause that identifies the client and based on that write what kind of image I want to insert as a `background-image` on the style applied to the `html body`

I searched a lot on the web and on the stack and found many articles that dealt with `conditional css` but none that dealt with image change

I decided to use `conditional css` and came:

```
    <body>
   <!--[if mso]>
     <style type="text/css">
         #photo {
           background-image: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/...');
           background-size:contain;
         }
     </style>
   <!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if !mso]>
      <style type="text/css">
         #photo {
         background-image: url('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1e0siJmU...');
         background-size:contain;
         }
      </style>
   <!--<![endif]-->
    <img id="photo">
    </body>
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work. tips? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Signatures are essentially being forwarded every time they're being used. I would guess that any conditional code is being stripped on initial send or even when a signature is imported and set up. There will definitely be some type of cleansing done to ensure their users aren't trying to insert Javascript or anything else malicious.

Further to that, Gmail also has a way to block images and the Outlook option can be turned off so that images are downloaded. No doubt other email clients are in the same boat.
Essentially, you'll never find a full proof way to display images for everyone. I would advise you respect the recipients decision and just build a solid signature that renders as expected.

Comment: Yep the first example `<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1e0siJmU...">` is the way to go.

Comment: I also thought the same as you, but I've seen people who manage to add a conditional CSS similar to mine. And then campaigns like mailchimp how do they get correct images displayed in all clients? There must be a way

Comment: If you have examples of email signatures with this code included, then please share. This would definitely be a learning opportunity for me and I'd love to see how it is done.
You mention Mailchimp but email templates are a completely different ball game to email signatures. The support for methods of image integration are a lot greater with email templates. Signatures are seen as a small sign off at the end of a typed and personal email and as such have very restrictive rendering capabilities.

Comment: With an email template in Mailchimp, you would have the freedom to add conditional CSS to either encode a base64 image or display a straight image path for a normal format.